# Error 404 while loading HTML into DIV by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have code that inserts HTML into a `DIV` container using `$.load()` from jQuery but I've noticed there's the error 404. This is HTML code

```
<div id="mathstudents"></div>
```

and `JavaScript`

```
var div = $('#mathstudents');
var url = '@(Url.Action("ListOfMathStudents", "Outer"))';
div.load(url, { page: 1 }, function() { alert('Finished'); });
```

The name of the action and controller is correct. I double checked that. The problem occurs when I have added the second parameter as a data: `{ page: 1 }`.

I tried this code below that is based on `$.get()` and it does work:

```
var div = $('#mathstudents');
var url = '@(Url.Action("ListOfMathStudents", "Outer"))';
$.get(url, { page: "1" }, function (data) {
    div.html(data);
});
```

I would prefer `$.load()` because as it is stayed on [website](http://api.jquery.com/load/) it allows to specify a portion of the the document to be inserted.

EDIT:
This is code of the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult ListOfMathStudents(int? page, bool? whichPage,
                                       int? sort, bool? asc,
                                       string filterType, string filterContent)
{
    IndexViewModel viewModel = new IndexViewModel();
    using (TestDBContext db = new TestDBContext())
    {
        viewModel.Students = getStudentList(db);
    }

    // Filtering
    if (filterType != null && filterContent != null)
    {
    }

    // Paging
    page = (whichPage == null) ? (page ?? 1) : (whichPage.Value ? page++ : page--);
    int maxPages = 0;
    int currentPage = getCurrentPage(page, viewModel.Students.Count(), out maxPages);
    viewModel.SPFDetails = new SPFDetails()
    {
        CurrentPage = currentPage,
        MaxPages = maxPages,
        MaxRecords = viewModel.Students.Count()
    };

    // Sorting
    if (sort != null)
    {
        viewModel.Students = sort == 1 ? viewModel.Students.OrderBy(x => x) : viewModel.Students.OrderByDescending(x => x);
    }

    viewModel.Students = viewModel.Students.Skip((currentPage - 1) * SPFDetails.GroupSize).Take(SPFDetails.GroupSize);

    viewModel.Students = viewModel.Students.ToList();
    return PartialView(viewModel);
}
```

EDIT2:
I've just read `$.load()` uses POST to transfer data. When I tried `$.post()` instead of `$.get()`, I've got the same result: ERROR 404. I though I'd have to provide the exact number of parameters for POST that match action signature and all input parameters. So I've changed the script to:

```
var div = $('#mathstudents');

var url = '@(Url.Action("ListOfMathStudents", "Outer"))';
div.load(url, {
    page: 1,
    nextPage: null,
    sort: null,
    asc: null,
    filterType: null,
    filterContent: null
});
```

but it still says there's the ERROR 404.

Comment: ZikO - can you add your controller code please in order to see how the *page* param is used...

Comment: It sounds like your routing is not set correctly if the addition of the page param is causing a 404. We can't really help diagnose a 404 though. Also, you will end up with duplicate ids in your page if you append the `#mathstudents` div gotten via AJAX to an existing `#mathstudents` div.

Comment: The parameters probably do not match the action's. Can you share its signature?

Comment: @jimtollan I have provided the code of my controller. I am surprised the `$.get()` method is working!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I guess there's only standard routing as I've not changed anything in the `RouteConfig` file. If I added the new routing, would the objects in routing match the set of input parameters in the action signature? Is it how it works? Sorry if I am confusing terms here I am not very good at proper naming things related to ASP.NET

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am really confused and puzzled when you mentioned the duplicating ids :/ Does it mean I would end up with a page with the same ids such as `<div id="mathstudents" id="mathstudents"></div>` or I'd just have two different ids in the same `div`. Thanks.

Comment: Re. duplicate ids, I mean you would end up with `<div id="mathstudents"><div id="mathstudents"></div></div>`, which is invalid. `id` attributes must be unique within the page.

Comment: I edited the question. It looks like POST does not work here. Can someone please provide an example how set the `MapRoute` if I want the POST method to work? I would be grateful!

Comment: @ZikO Take off HttpGet attribute from your action. And try to add HttpPost if you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change attribute of your action from `[HttpGet]` to `[HttpPost]`. As you mention, jQuery load function uses POST type. But it uses POST if data parameter provided, if non then it uses GET.

from api [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

Comment: Hi aleha, it's working. Thanks :) And sorry I am confused by your explanation regarding data parameter. Are you saying that if I use the second parameter [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) such as `$.load(url, { parameter: value })`, then `$.load()` switches automatically to POST?

Comment: @ZikO added quotes to ansver. As there said, if data is object (not String) then used POST.